# GSpread appending to specific column

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm currently using gspread's "append_row" function to append a string of text to the first column in the spreadsheet. However, I'd like to append the text to a different column than column one.

`

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import gspread

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open_by_url("url_to_spreadsheet").worksheet("Sheet1")


sheet.append_row(["some text"])
```

`

I tried using `sheet.append_row(["some text"])` to append text to a column in the spreadsheet, but it only appends to column one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put the value of `"some text"` to the specific column of the next row of the last row using gspread for python.

When `append_row` is used to an empty sheet, `range` can be used. But, when the values are existing in the sheet, even when `range` is used, the values cannot be put into the expected column. I'm not sure whether this is the current specification or a bug. So, in this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
sheet.append_row(["some text"])
```

#### To:

```
column = 3  # Please set the column number you want to put the value. 3 means column "C".
last_row = len(sheet.get_all_values())
sheet.update_cell(last_row + 1, column, "some text")
```

Or, when you want to use a list, please use the following sample.

```
column = 3  # Please set the column number you want to put the value. 3 means column "C".
last_row = len(sheet.get_all_values())
dst_range = gspread.utils.rowcol_to_a1(last_row + 1, column)
sheet.update(dst_range, [["some text"]], value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

#### References:

- [update_cell](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api/models/worksheet.html?highlight=update_cell#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.update_cell)
- [update](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api/models/worksheet.html?highlight=update#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.update)